# Naming your foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose you have a model `User` and a model `Challenge`.

One `User` can be the supervisor of a challenge. Therefor a `Challenge` has a `belongs_to` relation with the User.

The relation is declared as following
in `challenge.rb`:

```
  class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :supervisor, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

Resulting in the following `schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "challenges", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.string   "state"
    t.integer  "count"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false

    # Notable line: 
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

Should the foreign key in the schema be named `supervisor_id` or `user_id`?

Comment: Are there any other relationships between User and Challenge?

Comment: I would choose `supervisor_id` as there is a name of relation (you name the integer `count` not `integer`). `user_id` does not imply what is this relation (user who solved the challenge? user who posted one? user who supervise it?) and may confuse reader if in future any other relationship will be added.

Comment: As you're looking for opinions, I'd go with `supervisor_id`, as you may need to add more relationships between User and Challenge later.

Comment: There is another relation: a participant user participates in many challenges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, you would have a simpler time if you named it `supervisor_id` for 2 reasons:

- You can skip the `:foreign_key` modifier in the `belongs_to` declaration
- If you ever need another `belongs_to` relationship that links to a generic user, you can call that one `user_id` without needing to rename anything

Other than that, it really doesn't matter.  That is, Rails won't care.  And it certainly isn't worth the time for a 'heated discussion'.

Comment: It *does* matter somewhat, in my opinion, beyond simple "do it because it's the Rails convention". There is semantic meaning in the name of a foreign key; that meaning is lost if the foreign key simply reflects the name of the table it links to. It's valuable at the data level to be able to tell that the column doesn't point to an arbitrary "user" of a challenge, but to the user who *supervises* the challenge.

Comment: @meagar, it's only valuable at the data level to the extent that the column name is written in code.  As Rails would have it, any code referencing that column name should be made in the Challenge model that declares it - where this name is explicitly mentioned if different than the convention.  In other words, semantic meaning in the foreign key name is not considered very relevant in the Rails world.  I agree that this will not necessarily hold true with other frameworks and design patterns, but ActiveRecord prefers to work with the underlying data structure as abstracted away.